# Cant set related videos correctly after youtube video is played

Tags: iframe, youtube

I am trying to set the recommended videos after a youtube movie is played, to be the videos of that channel but I'm writing something wrong.
Here is my iframe logic:

```
<iframe 
 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID?listType=user_uploads&list=CHANNEL_ID?autoplay=1"
></iframe>
```

and here is the real code:

```
<iframe 
 src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/LKKQpX5ucGk?listType=user_uploads&list=UC-k6oG4r4vQjeoMZlEHzQmw?autoplay=1"
></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the related videos to be from the same channel by adding `rel=0` to your src

The following has your desired effect

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/boPZ_0E6X6s?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```